# How to get the QNetworkConfiguration UserChoice dialog?

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest

Qt docu says I can get a popup for the user to choose the `QNetworkConfiguration`. But how can I do this?

When I have

```
QNetworkConfiguration config;
QNetworkSession *networkSession = new QNetworkSession(config, &a);
networkSession->open();
```

how can I tell it I want the dialog. There is not `setType` function or ctor. What do I miss? Or am I just on the wrong platform (Win64)?

> UserChoice The configuration is a placeholder which will be resolved
>   to an actual configuration by the platform when a session is opened.
>   Depending on the platform the selection may generate a popup dialog
>   asking the user for his preferred choice.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/bearer-management.html only QNetworkConfigurationManager::defaultConfiguration() returns a configuration of type UserChoice

Comment: On my Win it is empty for a WIFI system (because of Qt bug) and no user choice also for a cabled system.